# Primefaces chart memory leak when refreshing with poll component

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have 10 charts in my page and I refresh them using `poll` component every 1 minute.
But after one hour i see that firefox and chrome got more that 1 GB of memory and sometimes even firefox crashes.

Is this a memory leak caused by primefaces chart?
How can I solve the problem?

Here is the source code for my example application:

In this code interval is set to 3 seconds to see the problem sooner!

```
<h:body>

    <h:form id="timerForm">
        <p:poll interval="3" widgetVar="timer" update=":chartPanel" autoStart="true" /> 
    </h:form>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="chartPanel">

        <p:lineChart id="chart1" value="#{chartController.model}"
                             legendPosition="nw" style="height:200px;width: 500px;" minY="0" />
        <p:lineChart id="chart2" value="#{chartController.model}"
                             legendPosition="nw" style="height:200px;width: 500px;" minY="0" />
        <p:lineChart id="chart3" value="#{chartController.model}"
                             legendPosition="nw" style="height:200px;width: 500px;" minY="0" />
        <p:lineChart id="chart4" value="#{chartController.model}"
                             legendPosition="nw" style="height:200px;width: 500px;" minY="0" />
        <p:lineChart id="chart5" value="#{chartController.model}"
                             legendPosition="nw" style="height:200px;width: 500px;" minY="0" />
        <p:lineChart id="chart6" value="#{chartController.model}"
                             legendPosition="nw" style="height:200px;width: 500px;" minY="0" />

    </p:panelGrid>

</h:body>
```

And here is the bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ChartController {

static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ChartController.class.getName());

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
}

private ChartSeries getData(String label) {
    ChartSeries data = new ChartSeries();
    data.setLabel(label);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        data.set(i, Math.random() * 1000);
    }
    if (data.getData().isEmpty()) {
        data.set(0, 0);
    }
    log.log(Level.INFO, "Chart loaded for :{0}", label);
    return data;
}

public CartesianChartModel getModel() {
    CartesianChartModel chartModel = new CartesianChartModel();
    chartModel.addSeries(getData("Data 1"));
    chartModel.addSeries(getData("Data 2"));
    chartModel.addSeries(getData("Data 3"));
    return chartModel;
}
}
```

When I close the browser, it completely releases memory.
And here is the source code to download:
I have uploaded the source code, it's a maven project, just download it and open it in your IDE and deploy it in your app server.

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/secmuo7vjasdaue/chart-bug.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component does not destroy resources before refreshing.
I found that this is a bug in version 3.3.1 and is fixed in 3.4-SNAPSHOT

Here is the reference:

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18286&hilit=chart+memory+leak

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4183