# Primefaces chart memory leak

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, charts, jqplot

I am using Primefaces version 5.3 for displaying a Chart component, which is updated every n seconds, specified by the user, using a `poll` component.

I have a huge problem with this component. At first, everything is working fine, the chart and the app run smooth. After a while though, my application starts to get slower and slower, until a point when it's completely unusable.

I managed to trace down the root of the problem. I think everytime the chart gets update, it doesn't get destroyed, but a new chart is being created.

I made the remote command below and called it via javascript 2000 times:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateChart" update="centerForm:dataChart" />
```

After it was completed, the app became very slow. This was without showing any kind of data, just calling this method and updating the chart. I suppose the problem lies here, but I couldn't find a solution to it.

This is my getter method, which is called everytime the chart is updated:

```
public LineChartModel getLineModel()
{
    return this.lineModel;
}
```

I even tried calling this javascript method, when the chart is updated, but without luck:

```
var plot;
function renderGraph() {
if (plot) {
    plot.destroy();
}
plot = PF('dataChart').plot;
plot.replot();
```

}
I found only this SO question related to this, but no luck neither [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643630/primefaces-chart-memory-leak-when-refreshing-with-poll-component)

Any thoughts what could be a solution for this problem? 
Thank you for your time reading this and helping me out.

Comment: is it a problem in all browsers?

Comment: Tried a newer version of PF? Does it still manifest there?

Comment: Yes, in every browser. I just tried with v6, but the problem still exists..

Comment: Then please create a [mcve] and post an issue in the PF github issuelist

Comment: OK, I'll do that!

Comment: Just submitted the issue: [pf-issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1912)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in the issue. Just to be sure they run 100% identical code